# Macbook Pro Battery Care

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging

I found [instructions about MacBook battery care](http://www.apple.com/batteries/notebooks.html), but it made me confused. I received my MacBook Pro yesterday. After unboxing, I used it for some time and then I fully charged the battery. I will be using this laptop as my primary device.

So, my question is, if I use my MacBook about 7-8 hours a day with the charger plugged in, will it be harmful for the battery? What is the recommended way?

Comment: @YasirAdnan This article maybe helpful http://gigaom.com/2013/06/22/extend-the-battery-life-of-your-macbook-no-matter-how-old-it-is/

Answer (score 2):

To get the most out of your MacBook Pro's battery, follow the [Notebook Battery advice from Apple](http://www.apple.com/batteries/notebooks.html): unplug and use your battery until empty about once a month, then charge back up to full.

If you need help following Apple's advice, use [Battery Guardian](http://www.dssw.co.uk/batteryguardian/); it is free and will remind you when to deplete your battery.